# How to fix tons of broken packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I apologize in advance for the poorly formated question: I don't know much about linux so I don't know what information to include.

I was really lazy about upgrading, and up until yesterday, I was still running jaunty. I wanted to upgrade to trusty, but of course you can't complete the upgrade in one step. So I downloaded the iso for the alternate cd install for Karmic and it ran just fine. Then, I did the same for Lucid, and it almost worked, but it said there was some problem with adobe-flashplugin. I removed adobe-flashplugin and now I have tons of broken packages. apt-get update and aptitude update don't work, giving me the message "unknown error executing gpgv". Furthermore, the alternate cd upgrade for precise pangolin doesn't work, saying that it "could not calculate the upgrades." Synaptic package manager isn't working properly either. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: You are running a very old release.I would suggest you for a fresh install instead of upgrading.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. I just really don't want to have to pick out what's important to me. That would probably be the smartest thing to do now that everything broke. I was just really hoping I could get around it because the upgrade to Karmic went so well.

Comment: Did you try upgrading using [`old-releases`](http://askubuntu.com/a/91821/158442) instead of the ISOs?

Comment: Well, I don't know if I did it right. I changed the sources in the sources-list to say old-releases instead of us.archive.ubuntu.com, but I'm still getting the gpgv errors when I run apt-get update.

Comment: Hi everyone: It turned out something was wrong with my libreadline. I fixed it and successfully upgraded to precise!

Answer (score 0):

- Download the trusty image
- Flash it on a CD drive or USB drive
- boot into the CD or USB
- Select Replace installation and wait
- Enjoy all packages wich all aren't broken